# Sending IR commands with Xiaomi Mi4

Tags: java, android, infrared

I am working on a remote control app for Android, I am able to send commands with Samsung, LG, and HTC phones.

I just noticed that some other apps added Xiaomi Mi4 to their compatibility list.

Tried searching online, couldn't find any material about sending IR commands with Xiaomi Mi4.

Any ideas?

Thanks